# How to setup a docker container networking on CoreOS?

Tags: networking, docker, coreos

I have a single bare metal machine running CoreOS and a bunch of Docker containers, e.g.`nginx` and `gitlab`.

`nginx` should be a reverse proxy for `gitlab` so it needs to have network connectivity and hostname resolution to the `gitlab` container.

I used to do this via `docker run --name nginx --link gitlab:gitlab ...` but that's deprecated and the Docker documentation recommends using Docker's "user defined networks".

I can create one of those with `docker network create ...` but I want it to be automatically created on boot.

How do I configure that in CoreOS's cloud-config? My first idea was to create a System unit that just runs the command. Is that how it supposed to be done?

Answer (score 1):

The more CoreOS way of doing this would be a fleet unit, then you can define the dependancies with your other units.

So you might have a fleet unit called `mynetwork` dependant on docker, and then your `nginx` and `gitlab` units would be dependant on `mynetwork`